# MKAnnotationView showing callout with no text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, mkannotationview

**Update**:Michael got it right. Here is my solution:

```
- (void) connectNextCarOnMainThread:(id)annotation{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(connectNextCar:) withObject:annotation waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void) connectNextCar:(id)annotation{
    Pin *pin = (Pin *)annotation;
    MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(pin.coordinate);
    MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 3, 3);
    if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
         zoomRect = pointRect;
    } else {
         zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
    }
    [mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
    [mapView selectAnnotation:pin animated:YES];

    NSInteger currentIndex=[self.annotations indexOfObject:annotation];
    if(currentIndex < [self.annotations count]){
        [self performSelector:@selector(connectNextCarOnMainThread:) withObject:[self.annotations objectAtIndex:currentIndex+1] afterDelay:5];
    }
}
```

---

I want to achieve a simple feature: center and select one of my annotations every X seconds. But I'm getting some strange behavior in my annotation callouts.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    if(self.movedToFitPins){
        for(id <MKAnnotation> pin in self.annotations)
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];
        self.movedToFitPins = NO;
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fakeCarConnections) withObject:nil];
    }
}

- (void) fakeCarConnections {
    for (Pin *annotation in self.annotations)
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval : 10.0];
        MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 3, 3);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect;
        } else {
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
        [mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
        [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
    }
}
```

So, what is happening is that I do focus on the Annotation, the callout bubble does open but with no text inside. If i click in the annotation, the callout opens up correctly with the text.
Here is the catch: if I comment the sleepForTimeInterval line, the code works fine, but I only see the last annotation since it passes trough all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UI modifications/messages should occur on the main thread. I'd suggest that you modify your looping code so that instead of a sleep it uses `performSelectorOnMainThread` after a time interval (and each subsequent call calls the next one). That way you won't block the main thread and will still get the desired effect.

Comment: Did works, thanks. I've updated my question with my solution. =)

Comment: You should update your `performSelector` call to explicitly use the main thread, since you are updating UI. Probably setting yourself up for random fails without that. It's a pain since you can't pass a delay to `performSelectorOnMainThread` I know - but might save a debugging nightmare later.

Comment: So I should make my `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` call a selector that all it does is call another selector using `performSelectorOnMainThread`?

Comment: Yes. We're coding for the 0.000001% here, but that is what makes it fun right?

Comment: Just updated my question with the lastest version, making sure that it's executing on the main thread. Thanks Michael =)